# How to get the account Id thanks to the lead's Id after the lead conversion?

Tags: apex, account, id, convert

After a lead conversion, I have to redirect the user to a Visualforce page (saveUrl on the URL) to examine some fields of the account to redirect the user then (depend of the values of the account fields).

Is it possible in Apex to get the account's Id of the lead after his conversion if I only have the lead's id?

Thank for the responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep - requery the lead record and look for convertedAccountId field. Google 'lead sobject' for sobject description of this.

Comment: It works !

Thanks, you are my hero ! :)